# Creating a reactive dataframe with shiny apps

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive-programming, plotly

I am trying to get this reactive to return a data frame that I can manipulate with plotly.

```
avghour <- reactive({
    result <- data.frame()
    start_date <- as.numeric(unlist(input$i6[1]))
    end_date <- as.numeric(unlist(input$i6[2]))
    mkw <- maxkwpeakdates[(maxkwpeakdates >= start_date & maxkwpeakdates <= 
                             end_date) & !is.na(maxkwpeakdates), ]
    mkw <- na.omit(mkw)
    mopkw <- maxonpeakkwdates[(maxonpeakkwdates >= x & 
                                 maxonpeakkwdates <= y) & !is.na(maxonpeakkwdates), 
                              ]
    mopkw <- na.omit(mopkw)
    mkwhour <- data.frame(as.data.frame(apply(mkw, 2, hour)))
    mopkwhour <- as.data.frame(apply(mopkw, 2, hour))
    mkwhour <- as.data.frame(sapply(mkwhour, tabulate, 24))
    mopkwhour <- as.data.frame(sapply(mopkwhour, tabulate, 24))
    mkwhour <- as.data.frame(apply(mkwhour, 1, mean))
    mopkwhour <- as.data.frame(apply(mopkwhour, 1, mean))
    result <- data.frame(mkwhour, mopkwhour)
    colnames(result) <- c("1", "2")
    return(result)
  })
```

I want to be able to graph the resulting data frame. When I debug my app it turns out that avghour is getting saved as a function and not as a data frame. The values that the reactive require are forcing the reactive to update properly but I just cant get the result saved as a data frame. Am I using reactive correctly? Do I need to be doing this another way?

**UPDATE**

```
I have changed my server code to be like this:

server <- function(input, output) {

  averages <- reactiveValues(hourly = avghour(input$'i6'[1], input$'i6'[2]))

  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    averages$hourly <- avghour(input$'i6'[1], input$'i6'[2])
  })

  output$"1" <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%  
      add_trace(type = 'bar',
                data=averages$hourly,
                x=~'1',
                y=~'2')
  })

}
```

getHourlyAverage is the same function as I had before. Now I am getting `error: operation not allowed without an active reactive context.` How can I use observeEvent and reactiveValues with user input?

Comment: Are you calling the reactive the right way? You need to call it using `avghour()`, not `avghour`.

Comment: Yes, when I am referencing it in plotly I am using avghour()$columnName.

Comment: Does my answer help at all?

Comment: Will have a look... Looks fine at first glance. What does `getHourlyAverage` look like.

Comment: There is no `getHourlyAverage` "as before" that I can see.

Comment: And I can't get `output$"1"` to work at all. What does the `plotlyOutput` side look like?

Comment: I changed getHourlyAverage to avghour to match the first code block. my function avghour needs to take a dateRange input (input$'i6'[1], input$'i6'[2]) and it should produce a dataframe. output$"1" is just refering to plotlyOutput("1") and should just display the graph.

Comment: I think it will work if you just use more conventional names for the x and the y columns. I don't think plotly can take strings.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: No but I feel like this is broader than my original question. I did get the reactive elements to work but now I have the problem of passing the user input. Ill take a day or two and look it over and if I can't figure it out ill post a different question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend storing the dataframes in a so-called `reactiveValues` list. They then have the same reactive properties as things calculated using `reactive` functions (in that other reactives that depend on them will be triggered when the originals change), but you can get at all of their elements to manipulate them.

In general, it is recommended that simple programs that can get away with only using reactive functions should do so, but I do find that frequently leads to a dead end when things get more complex because there is no logical place to store and update your data.

Note that the `reactiveValues` is a list, you can store more than one thing in there, and thus keep related things together. All of the members of that list will be reactive.

Here is a very simple example using plotly:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  actionButton("regen","Generate New Points")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  n <- 100  
  rv <- reactiveValues(m=data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n)))

  observeEvent(input$regen,{
    rv$m <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n))
  })

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly() %>%  add_markers(data=rv$m,x=~x,y=~y  )
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a screen shot to help visualize it:

[image]