# Pass a reactiveValues dataframe to a reactive expression

Tags: r, shiny

I have the simple shiny app below in which I store a dataframe in a `reactiveValues()` and after filter the `date` to pass it to a `reactive()` expression. But I get nothing as a result. Note that This `reactiveValues()` dataframe will be later subseted in more than one other reactive expressions and those expressions will be combined for the final result,therefore it just need to filtered only by `date` in the reactiveValues. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313629/subset-a-reactive-dataframe-in-r) is why I use it

```
    #ui.r
        shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Organizational Analysis"),
        sidebarLayout(

          sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("gr", "Group by:",
                        choices = c("val","Gender")
            ),
            sliderInput("Date Range",
                        "Dates:",
                        min = as.Date("2018-04-21","%Y-%m-%d"),
                        max = as.Date("2018-10-27","%Y-%m-%d"),
                        value=as.Date("2018-10-27"),
                        timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d")

          ),

          mainPanel(
           visNetworkOutput("network")
          )
        )

      )
    )

    #server.r
    library(shiny)
    library(visNetwork)
    library(geomnet)
    library(igraph)
    library(dplyr)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {


actors <- data.frame(name1=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                               "Esmeralda"),
                       name2=c("Ali", "Boby", "Cecilia", "Daviddff",
                               "Esmeraldagj"),
                       date=c("2018-10-27","2018-09-27","2018-10-17","2018-07-27","2018-04-21"),
                       val<-c(10,20,10,20,10))

  sampler<-reactiveValues(sampl=actors) 
  observe({
    s<-sampler$sampl %>% dplyr::filter( date>= input$DateRange[1] & date <= 
    input$DateRange[2])
    s
  })
      actors2<-reactive({
        actors<- actors %>% dplyr::filter( date>= input$Dates[1] & date<= input$Dates[2])
        actors

      })
      nodes2<-reactive({
        eids<-as.character(actors2()$name1)
        mids<-as.character(actors2()$name2)
        nodes<-data.frame(c(eids,mids))
        nodes<-unique(nodes)
        nodes$ID <- seq.int(nrow(nodes))
        colnames(nodes)<-c("label", "id")
        nodes<-nodes[,c(2,1)]
        colnames(actors2())[1]<-"id"
        nodes$id<-nodes$label
        nodes<-merge(x = actors2(), y = nodes, by = "id", all = TRUE)
        nodes$label<-nodes$id
        nodes [is.na(nodes)] <- "Unknown"
        nodes<-nodes[,c(1,5,4)]
        if(input$gr=="val"){
          nodes$color<-""

          for(i in 1:nrow(nodes)){
            if(nodes[i,3]==10){
              nodes[i,4]<-"green"
            }
            else if(nodes[i,3]==20){
              nodes[i,4]<-"orange"
            }
            else if(nodes[i,3]=="Unknown"){
              nodes[i,4]<-"red"
            }

          }
        }
        else if(input$gr=="Gender"){

        }
        nodes
      })


      #Edges
      edges2<-reactive({
        edges <- actors2()[,1:2]
        colnames(edges) <- c("from", "to") 
        edges
      })


      output$network<-renderVisNetwork(
        visNetwork(nodes2(), edges2(), width = "100%") %>%
          visIgraphLayout() %>%
          visNodes(
            shape = "dot",
            shadow = list(enabled = TRUE, size = 10)
          ) %>%
          visEdges(
            shadow = FALSE,
            color = list(color = "#0085AF", highlight = "#C62F4B")
          ) %>%
          visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, degree = 1, hover = T),
                     nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>% 
          visLayout(randomSeed = 11)


      )


    })
```

Comment: I don't think the code inside `observe()` below `sampler` is doing anything. What is it for?

Comment: yes just to show my approach. If you can make it work with yours no prob

Comment: I eyeballed your code and I think there's enough hint in my and Yifu's answer for you to try and improve the code. Not being rude, just that I don't want to go through all that code. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. You didn't convert `date` column in `actors` table to date format. It was just `character`
2. The following codes  doesn't assign `s` to `sampler`, I created another reactive value `n` to store this result using `n(s)`

```
 observe({
    s<-sampler$sampl %>% dplyr::filter( date>= input$DateRange[1] & date <= input$DateRange[2])
    s
  })
```

Fixed server code for you:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  actors <- data.frame(name1=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                               "Esmeralda"),
                       name2=c("Ali", "Boby", "Cecilia", "Daviddff",
                               "Esmeraldagj"),
                       date=lubridate::ymd(c("2018-10-27","2018-09-27","2018-10-17","2018-07-27","2018-04-21")), # convert character to date
                       val<-c(10,20,10,20,10))

  sampler<-reactiveValues(sampl=actors) 
  n <- reactiveVal() # create this value to store s in observe() below
  observe({
    s<-sampler$sampl %>% dplyr::filter( date>= input$DateRange[1] & date <= input$DateRange[2])
    n(s)
  })

  #n<-reactive({
  #  s()
  #})

  output$tab<-DT::renderDataTable({
    n()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `reactiveValues()` and associated code is needed here. If you agree then you can use my approach and I'll delete my answer (since yours is more comprehensive. Also suggest you to remove `ui` part from the answer since there are no changes there (?) and that the answer will be more concise. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to subset this dataframe later and I know that this can be achieved if this is stored in a reactiveValues instead of a reactive based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313629/subset-a-reactive-dataframe-in-r . The table is there just to check that the dataset is created. If your answer can do this then it is ok

Comment: Hi @Shree, thanks for the suggestion. I agree your version is simpler and it is also how I write codes. But as explained by firmo, the reactive value may be used in other places. So I tried to not modify too much original codes.

Comment: This reactiveValues dataframe will be later subseted in more than one other reactive expressions and those expressions will be combined for the final result,therefore it just need to filtered only by date in the reactiveValues

Comment: I have put almost all of my actual code to make my goal more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of what you probably need. Make sure the dates are in proper format throughout the code. -

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  actors <- data.frame(name1=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                               "Esmeralda"),
                       name2=c("Ali", "Boby", "Cecilia", "Daviddff",
                               "Esmeraldagj"),
                       date=c("2018-10-27","2018-09-27","2018-10-17",
                              "2018-07-27","2018-04-21"),
                       val<-c(10,20,10,20,10))

  sampler <- reactive({
    temp <- actors %>% 
      dplyr::filter(date >= input$DateRange[1] & date <= input$DateRange[2])
    validate(need(nrow(temp) > 0), "No data for selected dates")
  })

  reactive2 <- reactive({
   # sampler() %>% more code
  })

  reactive3 <- reactive({
   # sampler() %>% more code
  })      

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
    sampler()
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to subset this dataframe later and I know that this can be achieved if this is stored in a reactiveValues instead of a reactive based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313629/subset-a-reactive-dataframe-in-r . The table is there just to check that the dataset is created.

Comment: @firmo23 You can apply that additional filter in `sampler()` itself. Just include `validate()` condition after the date filter. See updated answer.

Comment: This reactiveValues dataframe will be later subseted in more than one other reactive expressions and those expressions will be combined for the final result,therefore it just need to filtered only by date in the reactiveValues

Comment: @firmo23 In that case you can simply pass on `sampler()` to other reactives. See updated answer. I don't think `reactiveValues() + observe()` approach is needed here. My code achieves the same thing but is more concise.

Comment: ok I have almost the actual code I have I would like to see your approach on this